# Rails 4 asset pipeline how to call function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I know this is simple but I need help. suppose I have a view where I have a checkbox like

```
<%= check_box_tag "sometext", "id", false, :onclick => "updateDeal()" %>
```

and I have a file in /assets/javascript/deals.js.coffee where I have this function

```
function updateDeal(){
  alert('call');
}
```

but when i click on checkbox i get an error of undefined method updateDeal any one can help??

Answer (score 1):

function is misspelled (it's typed fucntion in your code)

:)

Comment: that was misspelled here :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way also , but it requires jquery.

```
$("#id").change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
      alert("checked");
    }
    else{
      alert("not checked");
    }
 });
```

u can convert it to coffee script also. see: http://js2coffee.org/
copy and paste this code and you will get coffee script

Comment: You should specify in your answer that this solution requires JQuery, that is a dependency that Asnad may or may not want.